# Unable to restart my Nagios Job using EyesOfNetwork

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I am new to Nagios and EyesOfNetwork, I have added sample host in eyesOfNetwork under Nagios Configuration and later tried to Apply configuration by restarting the job and facing following error

Engine export process failed to complete successfully.
Export failed.
Nagios Sanity Check Failed. Did not write configuration files to production. Output is as follows:
NagiosExportEngine beginning export...
NagiosExportEngine Starting...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNdEf.png)

I am ready to share any configuration details of my application. Let me know if anyone have solution for this issue

Thanks, In advance.

I have created a sample windows application in my Virtual Box and i am trying to add the windows application into my eyesOfNetwork to monitor

Comment: run the nagios command for the “pre flight check” shown in your image from a shell on the server itself and share the output as text,  not an image, in your question

Comment: "sudo /srv/eyesofnetwork/nagios/bin/nagios -v /tmp/lilac-export-1/nagios.cfg"

this is the command used in server and attaching the error mentioned in screenshot

 "Engine export process failed to complete successfully.
 Export failed.
 Nagios Sanity Check Failed. Did not write configuration files to production. Output is as follows:
2023-11-30 11:03:33 NOTICE NagiosExportEngine beginning export...
2023-11-30 11:03:33 NOTICE NagiosExportEngine Starting..." ,

When the same command is used in server, there was no issue 
"No serious problems were detected during the pre-flight check"